# segment-polygon intersection

Tags: computational-geometry

Greetings,

I would like to detect if a segment only 'touches' a polygon or cross it.

The Figure

[image]

explains my doubt. How to know the difference between cases A and B?
Note that in both situations the red line crosses the polygons in two vertices, one touching by outside and other crossing by inside. I have a segment-segment intersection algorithm, but I don't know how to use it properly. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are your polygons always simple, or can they be complex as well?

Comment: Concave polygons without self-intersecting edges. Holes may exist.

Comment: not sure if you still have a question or not. Your comment to professor O'Rourke's answer seems to indicate you haven't, but you haven't accepted his answer (yet).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think there might not be any approach much easier than computing the details at a low level.
First, you will need robust code to compute the intersection between two segments.
This is discussed (with code) [here](http://cs.smith.edu/~orourke/books/compgeom.html). Once you have the intersection points, you need
to compute how the polygon boundary interacts with your segment in the neighborhoods of those
intersection points.  This is essentially
repeated `LeftOf( )` computations, using the notation in my book.
In your image, the segment passes through vertex *b*, while the adjacent vertices *a* and *c*
(in a consecutive sequence (*a,b,c*)) are both to the same side of *b*. Therefore, the segment
does not penetrate to the interior of the polygon in the neighborhood of *b*.  But if *a* and *c*
were on opposite sides of the segment, then it must penetrate.

Comment: Thanks a lot Prof. O'Rourke. The idea behind 'LeftOf' solves the problem when the segment intersects the polygon at vertices.

Answer (score 0):

Generalizing, an intersection may comprise many points.  For example, see http://cagd.cs.byu.edu/~557/text/ch7.pdf which discusses how planar curves intersect, and says tangent curves intersect at two points "properly counted", which is counter-intuitive. In the case of a convex polygon with a grazing line, does the intersection have two points "properly counted?"  In your case, are there two intersections with two points each?

So Prof. O'Rourke gives an algorithm for computing the number of points in the intersection, so to speak.  Pragmatically, should a package for computing intersections return the count of points in each intersection?