# QPolygonF/QLineF intersection

Tags: qt, computational-geometry

[QPolygonF](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qpolygonf.html) has methods to union, intersect, and subtract with other QPolygonFs but I need to perform an intersection test with a QLineF. This appears to be missing from the API.

I suppose I could do something like this:

```
if (polygon .containsPoint (line .p1 ()) != polygon .containsPoint (line .p2 ())
    return true;

QPointF a = polygon .back ();
foreach (QPointF b, polygon)
{
    if (QLineF :: BoundedIntersection == line .intersect (QPointF (a, b))
       return true;
    a = b;
}

return false;
```

There are probably some numerical or edge-case surprises lurking in the above, so I'd rather not.

Is there a provided method somewhere in the Qt API that I can't see?

Comment: Can't you just create a polygon with two points for the line and then intersect both polygons?

Comment: Perhaps, but it's kinda clunky, probably inefficient, and I would need guarantees that such zero-area shapes are numerically well-behaved.

Comment: I'm not aware of any other method to achieve this as I haven't faced this particular problem myself. If you don't find a Qt method to do that, take a look to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3742382/segment-polygon-intersection which explains how to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the answer is "no".

Answer (score 5):

The implementation of  QPolygonF::intersected is:

```
QPainterPath subject; subject.addPolygon(*this);
QPainterPath clip; clip.addPolygon(r);

return subject.intersected(clip).toFillPolygon();
```

i.e. QPolygonF uses QPainterPath methods to do the intersections.
So you could do:

- make a QPainterPath from the lines of the polygon
- make a QPainterPath from your line
- intersect them
- check the result with isEmpty()
- get the intersection point with boundingRect()

I DID NOT TRY THIS! You have to check this yourself. I am not sure if this is better in regard to numerical stability and performance than your solution, so you should write some tests.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, and it's a good one, but unfortunately its no improvement. You get the bounty for the effort though :-)